# Algorithm analysis relation of inner loop to a n/2 outside loop

Tags: java, algorithm, computer-science

I am having trouble figuring out the time complexity of this code:

```
public static void myfun1 (int n) {
    System.out.println("n = " + n);
    for (int k = 1; k <= n / 2; k++){
        System.out.println(k);
        for(int m = 1; m <= k; m++){
            System.out.println(k + ", " + m);
        }
    }
 }
public static void main(String[] args){
    myfun1(8);
}
```

When i ran it for n=8, the following was the output:

[image: Output]

I am thinking that the first loop will run (n/2) and that I have to multiply it by the inner loop. What I am having trouble with, is the inner loop.  Normally I would assume two nested loops are (n^2) but I feel that n/2 in the first loop is correct but I am not sure how the inner loop relates to it. I see that from the output for every k there are k number of loops done my m. For some reason my brain can't translate this relationship in terms of n. Can someone offer me some guidance on this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: O(n/2) is the same thing as O(n) because of the definition of O(n)... Something is O(n) if f(x) <= kx for all x > some number. In other words, constants don't matter, you can pull them out. O(n/2) is equivalent to O(n).

Comment: The outer loop is executed 'n/2' times, which as @nhouser9 stated, is O(n). The inner loop is executed 'm' times, the end being (n-1). We now have (n(n-1)). This is in the bound of O(n^2),

Comment: That makes so much sense now...wow... thank you. I just have one concern. So when you look at the output (link provided above) when n=8 I see the loops (in total) output 13 times. How does this "13" relate to our analysis.

Comment: don't print in the outer loops or you get wrong results. Correct result is 10.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me understand this I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop runs 1 time the first time
2 times the second time... up to `n/2`

so it runs like the sum of integers from 1 to `n/2` = `((n/2+1)*n)/4`

(For 8, it runs 10 times, add a counter to make sure)

So complexity is O(n**2) here.

Comment: Based on the output I ran in Java for n=8 the output(ignoring the first line) contained 13. So I am not sure if 20 is correct or if I am interpreting this correctly.

Comment: actually I made a mistake in my mental calculation of 20!! it is 10. But the formula is correct. You get more lines because you print in the outer loops as well.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you Jean!